# multiple ajax responses per function?

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

Let's say that I trigger multiple Python functions with an ajax call. Is there a way to receive multiple responses (to indicate that they have all succeeded?). An abstract example:

```
function triggerPython(){
 $.ajax({
     url:"/triggerPython",
     type:'POST',
     data: whatever,
     success: function(response){ 
         alert(response);
     }
 });
 }
```

The python:

```
class triggerPython(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        function_1()
        self.response.out("Function 1 done!")
        function_2()
        self.response.out("Function 2 done!")
        function_3()
        self.response.out("Function 3 done!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope that is not possible. Flushing the output towards the browser might **seem** like one approach but GAE does not do that. It sends the complete response at once and together. [Check the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Responses).

As an alternative, you can create another service (second call) that *polls* the progress of the first call. Note that there's a time limit of ~60 seconds for the response. Or if your use-case allows, try splitting the 3 processes and call one after the other.